# Is there one drive business account just like Google drive business account?

Tags: google-drive-api, onedrive, google-drive-realtime-api, service-accounts

I am familiar with the google drive service account which allows to use account for business purpose.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Is there similar service in one drive I am familiar with one drive for business, but it doesn't look like an alternative for service account.
if available can you tell me about available APIs.?

My main purpose is to store user uploaded files in the cloud not to collaborate with my colleagues which is provided by One-drive for Business.
These files uploaded must be available to all my colleagues, not only by me.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to your question. Part 1 is about a service account. Microsoft Graph/OneDrive APIs do have a similar notion, its called the client-credential flow a.k.a app-only tokens. You can read more about it here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service

Please note that the permissions to this application will need to be granted by the tenant administrator.

Part 2 of your question pertains to how you will be sharing the uploaded files with everyone in your organization. By default, no one will have access to the files you put in the cloud. You will need to share them out explicitly. You have two options here:

- Use the invite api to explicitly share the item with people in your organization:
  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_invite
- Create an organization sharing link(use scope='organization') and share the link with people you want to grant access to:
  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createlink